# SVN slow merging Adobe Illustrator (.ai) files

Tags: svn

We have art assets included in our repository and whenever merging branches svn takes roughly 10 minutes per .ai file to merge. These files range from 3mb to 60mb so I'm ruling out network speed as a limiting factor. I'm suspecting a lengthy diff operation is being done on the file. Is there a way to *tell* svn, either by setting MIME type or otherwise, to take latest revision of the file or to treat it as a binary file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion *usually* identifies non-text based files as some sort of MIME type and won't merge them. However, certain files (like PDF files), this doesn't always happen. I believe that Subversion looks at the first 512 bytes (maybe a more) of a file, and if it only sees text, will consider the files text. Some files (like PDF files) can contain text in their first 100 bytes and may fool Subversion into thinking these are text files. Why not examine the whole file? Because examining a 400Mb file might take a while.

If the Subversion property `svn:mime-type` is set as a non-text file, the file will not be merged. See the [Subversion online manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.props.special.mime-type) for details.

Two things you can do: One is to set your `$HOME/.subversion/config` file to turn on auto-props. Under the `[auto-props]` section of this file, add the line:

```
*.ai  = svn:mime-type=application/illustrator
```

Now, whenever you create an Illustrator file, it will automatically marked as a non-text file.

The other thing you may need to do is to create a pre-commit hook to force users to set this property whenever they add or edit a PDF file. I just happen to have such a [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook). This hook allows you to control who has commit access to a file or directory, enforce revision properties (like the commit message), ban particular file names, and enforce file properties (such as `svn:mime-type` and `svn:sol-style`).

Any file that has been added or edited that doesn't match the rules will cause the whole commit to fail. After a few failures due to file properties, users will edit their Subversion configuration to set the correct auto-props.

Oh, one more thing, find all Illustrator files in your repository and set the `svn:mime-type` to `application/illustrator`. Checkout the entire branch or trunk, and use `find` to do this:

```
$ find $workdir -name "*.ai" -exec svn propset svn:mime-type "application/illustrator" {} \;
```

Then commit the change before attempting to merge. This must be done with the two branches involved in the merge, but you probably want to do this for all of your active branches.

Answer (score 1):

Subversion often attempts to guess at mime-types but it may not always get it right.

Anything with a MIME-type starting with `application/` is treated as binary, so set `svn:mime-type` on your `.ai` files to `application/illustrator` to tell Subversion that they're binary (that's also the correct MIME-type for those files).